# iOS Launch a FGallery with start point

Tags: ios, gallery

I wonder if we can launch the FGallery component at a given start point. 
https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone

I tried to use the loadFullsizeImageWithIndex: method used by the thumbnails grid but... fail.

Anyone did that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the image the controller starts with, try

```
gallery.startingIndex = 1; // or whatever number
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your proposition didn't work for me.
But I found the gotoImageByIndex:animated: method who works perfectly ;)

Comment: `startingIndex` worked for me if I set it right after `alloc`+`init`.